# PHP Regex @ vs /

Tags: php, regex

I noticed some users use @ vs "/" in PHP regular expressions, is there a difference between the two? I'm assuming it's user preference to handle "/"s within a string.

```
$body = preg_replace("@<script[^>]*>.+</script[^>]*>@si", "", $body);
```

vs

```
$body = preg_replace("/<script[^>]*>.+<\/script[^>]*>/si", "", $body);
```

Comment: No difference, just habits

Comment: You are correct. Both are valid delimiters for a regex.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: The @ people are trying to avoid [Leaning Toothpick Syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome).

Comment: @AndyLester I wouldn't say that.  In my case, I'm using MongoDB to store regular expressions already, so my toothpicks are sometimes 3-4 levels deep, using @ would have saved me a ton of extra chars.

Comment: @MKNWebSolutions: I don't see that I have said anything that disagrees with you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [PHP Manual on regex delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

> A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace
>   character.

So essentially there is no difference between using slash or `@` or `#`. However keep in mind that **chosen delimiter must not appear in the regex itself** otherwise you will need to escape that character.

**Tip:** Since PCRE allows `any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace` as delimiter, sometimes it is better to use control characters as delimiters when you can't predict the content of regex being used. See below example:

```
$repl = preg_replace('^K^foo^K', 'bar', 'foo.txt' );
```

Here this code is using a control character `^K` (typed as `ctrl-V-K` on shell)

Comment: Side note: `can't predict the content of regex` -> You mostly should use `preg_quote()`

Comment: @HamZa: Totally agree

Comment: Incidentally, it is not PCRE that is interpreting the delimiter, but PHP itself: see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482377/php-regex-delimiter-whats-the-point

Answer (score 3):

Using `/` makes it harder to put a `/` in the regex or replacement. Using `@` makes it harder to put a `@` in the regex or replacement. Other than that, there is no difference.