# Why is my $_SESSION variable disappearing?

Tags: php, http, session, post, server

I have a function

```
$capdir = get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/captcha/';
$capmap = array(
    'cat' => $capdir . 'Captcha_Cat.png',
    'dog'  => $capdir . 'Captcha_Dog.png',
    'fish' => $capdir . 'Captcha_Fish.png'
);

function set_animal_captcha ( )
{
    global $capmap;
    // returns image url of random animal and stores in session storage
    // a reference to that animal
    $randAnimal = array_rand($capmap, 1);
    $_SESSION['animal'] = $randAnimal;
    die($capmap[$randAnimal]);
}
```

which is fired on page load and which I've confirmed is working successfully. Then I have a function

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_contact', 'contact');
add_action('wp_ajax_contact', 'contact');

// $nameMap is a map of input names to table cells in the email
// e.g. <input name="email" value="myemail@gmail.com"/> gets made into the row <tr><td><b>Email Address:<b></td><td>myemail@gmail.com</td></tr>
// by the mapping 'email' => 'Email Address' in the array 
$nameMap = array(
    'name' => 'Name', 
    'email' => 'Email Address', 
    'phone' => 'Phone Number', 
    'comments' => 'Stuff in text box'
);

// https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; 
function contact ( )
{
    global $nameMap, $headers;

    $info = array(
        // name good as long as its not empty
        'validName' => (strlen(trim($_POST['name'])) > 0 ? true : false), 
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address            
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation
        'validEmail' => (preg_match("!^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$!", trim($_POST['email'])) == 1 ? true : false), 
        'validPhoneNumber' => (preg_match("!^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$!",trim($_POST['phone'])) == 1 ? true : false), 
        // if answer to captch equals animal in session storage
        'correctAnimal' => ($_SESSION['animal'] === trim(strtolower($_POST['capanswer']))) 
    );
    // see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482377/php-regex-delimiter-whats-the-point about why "!" is around the regexes
    if (!$info['validName'] || !$info['validEmail'] || !$info['validPhoneNumber'] || !$info['correctAnimal'] ) // if invalid name, email or phone number
    {
        $info['sentEmail'] = false;
    } else {
        // inputs contained valid values
        // contstruct email body
        $emailMsg = '<html><body><h3>Someone submitted a contact form ...</h3><table>';
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) if (array_key_exists($key, $nameMap)) $emailMsg .= '<tr><td><b>' . $nameMap[$key] . ':</b></td><td>' . $value . '</td></tr>';
        $emailMsg .= '</table></body></html>';

        // attempt to send email and set 'sentEmail' key accordingly
        $info['sentEmail'] = mail("myemail@gmail.com", "A Comment Was Submitted",$emailMsg,$headers) ? true : false;
    }

    echo json_encode($info); 
    die();
}
```

which is fired when a form is submitted on the page, but I've figured out that the

```
$_SESSION['animal']
```

is not defined when that function is fired. What are the possible reasons for this.

(Oh yea, and as you see, I always comment out citations to Stack Overflow posts that I copy-paste into production code haha)

Comment: Do you call `session_start` anywhere?

Comment: yes, do a `session_start();` at top.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @andrewsi in the header of my page I have ` if  (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)  {  session_start();  }`

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would check is if cookies are disabled on the client.

Without cookies, I believe the session will reside in memory on the server for the full execution of the script upon initial request -- and then disappear before the next page request is made.

Is your entire $_SESSION disappearing, or just 'animal'?

Comment: I just verified that there are other session variables at the time the function is invoked