# Caret (^) seems to escape forward slash when used as "not" in Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, lexer

I'm working on a javascript lexer for a side project at the moment, and when running it across a test codebase I came across a regex that our lexer doesn't like:

`/^(https?|ftp|tel|mailto):(\/\/|[^/])[^ ]+(\/|$)|^[^: ]+(\/|$)|^[\w.]+:\d+(\/|$)/`

The problem is this unescaped forward slash here:
`[^/]` which our lexer is interpreting as a terminator for the regex literal.

I've tested this in node and chrome v8 and it appears to be valid syntax. However I can't seem to find any documentation to state that use of the `^` caret as `NOT` in a javascript regex also functions as an escape character for forward slash `/`.

Could someone help me find the documentation or an official explanation of the rules here?

Comment: It's not the caret but the character class. [_In most regex flavors, the only special characters or metacharacters inside a character class are the closing bracket `]`, the backslash `\`, the caret `^`, and the hyphen `-`_](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: Ah great thank you @Phil - this was the info I needed to search for the right information 

Comment: As @Phil said, it has nothing to do with the caret. You'd see the same thing with `[/]`.

Comment: did yuio forgot to escaple it here `[^/]` ? Amazing that JS don't care inside char class, but looks like yuio lexer does See [/\/\[^/\]*\//](https://regex101.com/r/SXleK0/1) and 

[/\/\[^\/\]*\//](https://regex101.com/r/EGMI1g/1)

Comment: Notable exceptions are PCRE and Ruby, which will raise an error if an unescaped forward slash is present in a character class.

Comment: @Cary: In what context does PCRE use `/` as a special character? I've only used it as a C API and I don't recall ever running into `/` as other than a regular character.. But it's a big API, and I haven't exercised all of it by any means.

Comment: @rici, I can’t say about PCRE, I only tested it. `[^/]` brings up "pattern error" at regex101.com. In Ruby a regex can be defined `r = /abc/`, which explains why an unescaped forward slash cannot appears outside a character class, but why in cannot appear inside a character class I cannot explain.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Ok. I think that's an artefact of PHP. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482377/php-regex-delimiter-whats-the-point. Regex101 does let you change the delimiter

Comment: Thanks @rici. I didn't know that about Regex101.